# Obtener el valor de un campo de un campo

Tags: jsf, jpa

Tengo el siguiente codigo, encargado de registrar ventas, lo que intento traer es el precio de un producto, pero no me trae ningun precio, solo retorna NULL, estoy trabajando JPA, JSF

[image: Imagen del Codigo]

```
    public String redireccion() throws ParseException {
    //FORANEAS
    venta.setIDCliente(clienteFacade.find(cliente.getIDCliente()));
    venta.setIDProducto(productoFacade.find(producto.getIDProducto()));
    //AUTOINCREMENTALES, DATOS CALCULADOS
    venta.setIDVenta(Integer.SIZE);
    venta.setPrecio(producto.getPrecio());
    //INSERTAR
    ventaFacade.create(venta);

    return "";
}
```

Aqui es donde llamo a las respectivas entidades:
[image: Entidades]

```
 public controladorVentas() {
}
private Venta venta;
private Usuario usuario;
private Cliente cliente;
private Producto producto;

@EJB
private VentaFacade ventaFacade;
@EJB
private UsuarioFacade usuarioFacade;
@EJB
private ClienteFacade clienteFacade;
@EJB
private ProductoFacade productoFacade;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    venta = new Venta();
    usuario = new Usuario();
    cliente = new Cliente();
    producto = new Producto();
}
```

Por ultimo, el formulario:
[image: Formulario]

Comment: producto.getPrecio() depende de una busqueda por id, que no esta compartida en este código, para que genere el precio correcto debe de relacionarse al ID del producto buscado.  debes compartir datos del jpa, entity, mvc o recorido que ejecutas.

Comment: Pues, realmente mediante un formulario, ingreso el ID del producto, que lo recibe la linea 92, ya actualizo el post con mas imagenes

Comment: lo ideal es que detalles el código y no imagenes pero a simple vista veo que no tienen el name los imputs chequea esa parte .

Comment: Dudo que sean los names, ya tengo otros modulos donde recibo datos de la misma manera y no me dan problemas, el tema de este modulo, es que es la primera vez en que intento traer un campo que no tiene llave primaria, entonces la verdad no se muy bien como hacerlo

Comment: los @NamedQuery son los originales o creado personalizados.

Comment: ¿En las entidades? son los que mapea netbeans de la BD

Comment: cuando llamas una entidad sin llave, obtienes el objeto completo, para obtener el producto especifico debes ejecutar la consulta del mapa en donde este el id del producto y no la del objeto completo.   se puede trabajar desde la generica o hacer la propia segun la necesidad o relacion con las demas entitys

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: estaimad@  @Kr4k3n  el formulario si lee el código del producto?

Comment: Sip, si lo lee, pero la verdad sigo con la duda de como obtener el precio con ese ID de producto

Comment: Supongo que tendré que trabajar con consultas, pero la verdad no tengo claro como hacerlo

Comment: Falta compartir información como interfaces, daos entitys, etc, aunque sea el fragmento en donde este el producto.

Answer (score 0):

DAO

```
public Sala obtenerSala(Integer sala) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "[AppDAO][obtenerSala]");
            List<Sala> listaRespuesta = null;
            Sala respuesta = null;
            Query query;
            try {
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Nivel.findByCodigoSala");
                query.setParameter("codigosala", sala);
                listaRespuesta = query.getResultList();
                if (listaRespuesta != null && !listaRespuesta.isEmpty()) {
                    respuesta = listaRespuesta.get(0);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                respuesta = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return respuesta;
        }
```

la entidad (Resumen del mapeo)

```
/**
 *
 * @author Pperez
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "sala")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findBySala", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s WHERE s.sala = :sala"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findByNombreSala", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s WHERE s.nombreSala = :nombreSala"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findByTelefono", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s WHERE s.telefono = :telefono"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findByCodigo", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s WHERE s.codigo = :codigo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sala.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT s FROM Sala s WHERE s.direccion = :direccion")})
```

sus contructores

```
public Sala() {
    }

    public Sala(Integer sala) {
        this.sala = sala;
    }

    public Sala(Integer sala, String nombreSala, String telefono, String codigo, String direccion) {
        this.sala = sala;
        this.nombreSala = nombreSala;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public Integer getSala() {
        return sala;
    }

    public void setSala(Integer sala) {
        this.sala = sala;
    }

    public String getNombreSala() {
        return nombreSala;
    }

    public void setNombreSala(String nombreSala) {
        this.nombreSala = nombreSala;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
```

la busqueda para obtener un id

```
if (request.getParameter("objetoEditar") != null) {
            codigoSala = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("objetoEditar"));
            sala = dao.obtenerSala(codigoSala);
                
            String nombre = "";
            if (sala != null) {
                sala = new Sala();                    
                
                procesado = dao.actualizarSala(sala);
                if (procesado) {
                    System.out.println("Registro actualizado correctamente");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error al actualizar registro");

                }

            }
        }
```

ten en cuenta que puede haber interfaces.